# What do you do when the lags in ACF are on the edge of significance? How would you descibe this ACF and PACF plot?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, model-selection, acf-pacf

I have caluclated the first differences of a process and now created an ACF and PACF plot and I honestly don't know how to interpret it. I thought that it is an AR(1) process but I see some significant lags later then the first lag, but they look like they are close to the edge of significance.
What should be the order of this process? [image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to CV. Would periodicity (seasonality) at the indicated lags make sense in your application?  That's perhaps the most fundamental judgment to apply.  Relying on "significance" is not good because there are multiple independent comparisons going on and the significance bands are only approximate anyway.

Comment: so how would you select the order of AR and MA?

Comment: As I described.  I am trying to suggest that if you want concrete help, then consider supplying more contextual information and describe your data.